# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency:

Tags: html, css, reactjs, api, react-hooks

I'm  building a webapp with react and i get this warning:

```
src\Containers\App.js
  Line 30:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'API_KEY'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  Line 36:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'API_KEY'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Here the App.js code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import 'tachyons';

const App = () => {

  const API_KEY = `...`;

  const [searchField, setSearchField] = useState('');
  const [countryField, setCountryField] = useState('');  
  const [currentData, setCurrentData] = useState(null); 
  const [oneCallData, setOneCallData] = useState(null); 

  useEffect(() => { 
    fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Cinisi&units=metric&appid=${API_KEY}`)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(dataRecived => {
        setCurrentData(dataRecived);
      })
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=38.1562&lon=13.1073&units=metric&exclude=current,minutely,alerts&appid=${API_KEY}`)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(dataRecived => setOneCallData(dataRecived))
  }, []);
...
```

thank in advance anyone who tries to give me an answer

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook and https://namespaceit.com/blog/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that type of refactoring:
Component should have only one **useEffect**.

Where **fetchData1** and **fetchData2** should have more meaningfull names.

```
  const fetchData1 = useCallback(() => {
    fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=38.1562&lon=13.1073&units=metric&exclude=current,minutely,alerts&appid=${API_KEY}`)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(dataRecived => setOneCallData(dataRecived))
  }, [API_KEY]);

  const fetchData2 = useCallback(() => {
    fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Cinisi&units=metric&appid=${API_KEY}`)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(dataRecived => {
        setCurrentData(dataRecived);
      })
  }, [API_KEY]);


  useEffect(() => { 
    fetchData1()
    fetchData2()
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
```

Comment: Now I have this warning: 

`Line 42:6:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'fetchData1' and 'fetchData2'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

Comment: as workaround disable it by line:

Comment: // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Comment: explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook

Comment: ok and thanks for the answer